# SwiftUI, macOS, PDFView, The "Remove Highlight" context menu does not work

Tags: swiftui, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKitView: NSViewRepresentable to present the pdf page in SwiftUI. Seems we already have some useful built-in functions in the context menu. However, the highlight manipulation functions are not functional - I can neither delete the highlight annotation nor change the color/type of the current pointed highlight annotation.
The "Add Note" and other page display changing functions work well.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the color options, I tried to trace function calls on PDFView when clicking the colors, using SwiftTrace, and I'm convinced it is some leftover private APIs that are not usable. It seems it calls the private method `_updatePDFScannerResultHighlightAtPoint` of PDFView, but there's no way to overwrite it.

For the "Remove Highlight" item, it fires the "_removeMarkup" action, so it can be implemented like that:

```
@IBAction func _removeMarkup(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem?) {
    // implement own markup removal logic
}
```

Comment: It might be dependable on the PDF file, since the format is extensive, but normally Apple's Preview is able to change the color or remove annotations even after restarts.